# How can I get the all kinds of date and time format list from OWA?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

Like the screenshot. When I select a language then there will be a list of date and time format corresponding support. And if there is an API or function that I can get the all kinds of time format and date format at outlook web application(OWA).
I need to format all kinds of date and time format to a standard date and time format.

[image: Microsoft Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

Run Fiddler or the built-in browser debugger to look at the response to this request: https://server/owa/service.svc?action=GetRegionalConfiguration&EP=xxxx&ID=xxxx&AC=xxxx

All the SupportedShortDateFormats and SupportedShortTimeFormats are at the bottom.